# Starting to make an application for Android

Tags: java, android, facebook

So I got this idea that I want to implement as an Android application. Now what I have learned so far is Java, C and C++. As I understand, Java would be the smartest choice right? Have to mention tough, my experience is of a 1st year CS student's.

So I basically want to make a application that you can launch from the phone and it will also have a little database and fetch info into it from the users Facebook account.

So my questions are these:

The facebook part seems to be the hardest one to me. How is this done? Are there any articles around where I could read about it.

Second is, should I develop the application in Java?

And third one is...  If I do it in Java, I see that Google has a lot of stuff up for learning all of it. It also features two development kits. One is a stable version which works with eclipse and the other one is a preview thing which is a 0.xx version.

The second one seems to have all thoes fancy thing tough like having the phone preview on the screen all the time so that you can see how it looks like on the phone. And it seems to me that the Eclipse version does not have such features. So which one would be smarter to pick?

Comment: Would be great to state the reason of downvotes. That way I can write the question better next time.

Comment: There is only one downvote and that is probably because the question is opinion based and therefore deemed off-topic. No downvote from me but one to close instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, most apps for android are written in Java and with Eclipse. I would recommend you to do the same, because it is the easiest way at the moment (IMHO).

The Android Studio is still in the alpha state (as you said), so it can have some bugs. That's why you should use Eclipse (Android Studio looks great though).

Two simple links to put you in the right direction ;)
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=cn
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Edit for "how apps looks like in eclipse":

You have 3 options in eclipse to get a view of your app:
1. The xml-layout builder: in Android, you can create the layout of the app via xml or code. In Eclipse you have a preview of your applayout which you designed in xml [(How it looks like)](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/mobile/uploads/legacy/107_Android-Layout/android-layout_figure1.png)
2. Upload the app on your phone and watch it
3. Upload it on an android-emulator, so you don't have to use a phone

Comment: But how do the developers who use Eclipse see how the application look like on Android?  You have to manually put it into a phone each time you test?

Comment: I added an answer to your questions ;)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link for starting android apps development https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=cn

Facebook is providing separate SDK for integrating with android apps & this link will help you  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/